# Download dotenv job artifact via GitLab API

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I'm trying to download dotenv artifact called `release.env` from the latest job related to branch `feature/tests-update` but API returns `404` error.

API docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/14.8/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#download-a-single-artifact-file-by-job-id

Request example:

```
curl -v --get --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <TOKEN>" --data-urlencode "job=create-release" "https://<gitlab-host>/api/v4/projects/2/jobs/artifacts/feature%2Ftests-update/raw/release%2Eenv"
```

GitLab community 14.8.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant parts of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `artifacts:reports:dotenv` artifacts are not exposed by the API. Only files in the artifacts archive (e.g. in `artifacts:paths:`) can be retrieved from this endpoint.

You are, however, able to [download the dotenv reports from the UI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#download-job-artifacts).

As far as I can tell, this seems to be an oversight in the jobs API.

You can see that the jobs API lists dotenv reports in its artifacts with a filename of `.env.gz`:

```json
...
 'artifacts': [{'file_type': 'trace',
   'size': 9954,
   'filename': 'job.log',
   'file_format': None},
  {'file_type': 'dotenv',
   'size': 66,
   'filename': '.env.gz',
   'file_format': 'gzip'}],
...
```

However, even if you use the filename `.env.gz`, it seems you cannot download this file from the API.

As a workaround, you can add your `release.env` file to `artifacts:paths:` and retrieve it in the way you described.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I've added another job to save `release.env` as a standard artifact but still getting the same 404 error even for that.

Comment: @Eugene 404s may occur if your credentials don't have necessary access level for the project. Triple-check your credentials and URL are correct. As a test, I was able to verify this works on one of my own public projects: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/31238106/jobs/artifacts/feature%2Ftests-update/raw/release.env?job=MY_JOB`